# Extracting two columns from exported iTunes playlist

Tags: python, file, csv

My friend wanted me to send her a list of songs from one of my iTunes playlists, so I exported the playlist within the app itself.  It comes as a plain text file, where each field is separated a `'\t'` and each line is separated by a `'\r'`. Since there is so much extraneous information, I decided to write a Python script that would delete all fields but the song title and artist name.

How is the design and format of my code? How does it fit in with Python best practices? Is there a much easier way to do accomplish the same job that I just overlooked?

The input file looks like:

> ```
> Name\tArtist\tComposer\tAlbum\tGrouping\tGenre\tSize\tTime\tDisc Number\tDisc Count\tTrack Number\tTrack Count\tYear\tDate Modified\tDate Added\tBit Rate\tSample Rate\tVolume Adjustment\tKind\tEqualizer\tComments\tPlays\tLast Played\tSkips\tLast Skipped\tMy Rating\tLocation
>
> You Shook Me All Night Long\tAC/DC\t\tThe Very Best\t\tHard Rock\t5468228\t212\t\t\t9\t\t2001\t4/17/12, 2:29 PM\t4/17/12, 2:26 PM\t192\t44100\t\tMPEG audio file\t\t\t5\t3/12/13, 10:41 PM\t\t\t\tMacintosh HD:Users:UserName:Music:iTunes:iTunes Media:Music:AC_DC:The Very Best:09 You Shook Me All Night Long.mp3
> ```

The output file looks like:

> ```
> Name\tArtist\t
>
> You Shook Me All Night Long\tAC/DC\t
>
> Miss Murder\tAFI\t
> ```

My code is:

```python
from sys import argv

def main(file):
    with open(argv[1], 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        newdata = data.split('\r')
        output = []
        for line in newdata:
            tabc = 0
            newline = ""
            for char in line:
                newline += char
                if char == '\t':
                    tabc += 1
                    if tabc == 2: break
            output.append(newline)
        outPutString = '\n'.join(output)
    with open(argv[1][:-4]+'Out.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(outPutString)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = argv[1]
    main(file)
```

Comment: Interesting question; sounds like this tool could be handy!

Comment: 21st century mix tape.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple mistake**

The function `main` takes a filename as an argument but doesn't use it. Instead, it retrieves it from `argv`.

Also, `filename` would be a better name for a filename than `file`.

Answer (score 2):

### Easier solution

It would be easier to use a more specialized tool.  It could be a one-line [`awk(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html) script:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\r" } { print $1 "\t" $2 }' In.txt > Out.txt
```

The only non-trivial part is that you have to override the record separator character.

### Python

I like that you used `with` blocks for opening files.  The program could use some improvement, though:

- Make use of the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module to open files specified on the command line.  The tricky bit, once again, is overriding the line separator.  Since Python 2.5, `fileinput.input()` accepts a `mode` parameter, in which you can specify [universal newline](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) support.
- Avoid reading the entire file, and operate on a line at a time instead.  It simplifies your program and scales better (not that your iTunes library would ever be huge enough to break your program, but it's a good programming practice).
- Iterating a character at a time is tedious.  I recommend making use of [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).
- Hard-coding the output filename hurts the reusability of your program.  It would be better to parameterize the output filename.  Even better, I recommend just printing to standard output and redirecting the output using the shell.

The result is quite simple:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(mode='rU'):
    columns = line.split("\t", 2)   # <-- The 2 is optional, but I consider it good practice
    print "\t".join(columns[:2])
```

Comment: How might I redirect the output in the shell? I'm on a mac using Terminal.

Comment: When you invoke the Python program from the shell, append `> Out.txt` — similar to the `awk` example.

Answer (score 1):

The middle part would be simpler this way:

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    output = []
    for line in fh:
        parts = line.split('\t')[:2]
        output.append('\t'.join(parts))
```

Improvements:

- `filename` should be a parameter received by the method, instead of `argv[1]`
- No need for the `'r'` parameter in `open`, as that's the default anyway
- `file` is a built-in name in Python, so it's better to name differently, for example `fh`
- No need to read the entire data and then split by `\r`, you can read line by line from `fh` directly
- Instead of iterating over the characters in the line, it's easier to just split it by `\t`

It may seem inefficient to split by `\t`, which might parse the entire line when you only need the first two columns.
I'm not sure if that's a serious concern.
Splitting by `\t` has the advantage of simplicity and flexibility in case you later decide you want some other columns as well.
But if that bothers you, here's an alternative that only processes up to the second column:

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    output = []
    for line in fh:
        first_two_tabs = line[:line.index('\t', line.index('\t') + 1)]
        output.append(first_two_tabs)
```

**UPDATE**

As [@pjz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11776/pjz) pointed out in a comment, the solution with `split` can still be efficient by using a `maxsplit=2` parameter like this:

```
        parts = line.split('\t', 2)[:2]
```

Also, instead of accumulating the lines in a list,
you could process the input and write the output at the same time like this:

```
filename_out = filename[:-4] + 'Out.txt'
with open(filename) as fh_in:
    with open(out_filename, 'w') as fh_out:
        for line in fh_in:
            parts = line.split('\t', 2)[:2]
            fh_out.write('\t'.join(parts) + '\n')
```

Comment: A more efficient 'efficient way' would be to do `parts =  line.split('\t',2)[:2]` which limits it to two splits (so three parts), of which you only care about the first two.  Also, you could print as you go instead of storing everything into an output list.

Comment: Good points, updated my post, thanks @pjz!